# ros2_canopen implementation motor

Tags: ros2, motor, ros-canopen

I implemented the ros2_canopen Package for my Motor. So, the device started and i configured all the stuff with the yaml file. My yaml file can you see below:

```
options:
 dcf_path: "@BUS_CONFIG_PATH@"
 
master:
 node_id: 5
 driver: "ros2_canopen::MasterDriver"
 package: "canopen_master_driver"
 baudrate: 500
 sync_period: 10000
 reset_communication: false
 
nodes:
 motor1:
  node_id: 0x02
  dcf: "eds-file"
  dcf_path: Pfad
  package: "canopen_proxy_driver"
  driver: "ros2_canopen::ProxyDriver"
  polling: true
  period: 10
  reset_communication: false
  tpdo:
   1:
    enabled: true
    cob_id: "auto"
    transmission: 0x01
    mapping:
    - {index: 0x3302, sub_index: 0} # actual speed
    - {index: 0x3202, sub_index: 0} # actual pos
  rpdo: 
    1:
      enabled: true
      cob_id: "auto"
      mapping:
      - {index: 0x3301, sub_index: 0} # target speed
      - {index: 0x3201, sub_index: 0} # target pos
```

I configured the PDOs as you can see in my yaml file and the output if i start the launch file looks good.

```
[device_container_node-1] Found rpdo mapped object: index=3301 subindex=0
[device_container_node-1] Found rpdo mapped object: index=3201 subindex=0
[device_container_node-1] Found tpdo mapped object: index=3302 subindex=0
[device_container_node-1] Found tpdo mapped object: index=3202 subindex=0
[device_container_node-1] [WARN] [1705334668.604024023] [motor1]: Wait for device to boot.
[device_container_node-1] [ERROR] [1705334668.609367057] [motor1]: Boot Issue: Value of object 1018:01 from CANopen device is different to value in object 1F85 (Vendor-ID).
[device_container_node-1] [INFO] [1705334668.609376484] [motor1]: Driver booted and ready.
[device_container_node-1] [INFO] [1705334668.609508406] [motor1]: Starting with polling mode.
[device_container_node-1] [INFO] [1705334669.058086137] [motor1]: Slave 0x2: Switched NMT state to START
```

My problem is, that is nothing published over the PDOs topic. Do I miss something? Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Henne